# Android Java ArrayList the largest size possible

Tags: java, android, arrays, memory, arraylist

I have class model:

```
 class MySongs {

      private int song_id;
      private int song_likes;
      private int song_plays;
      private String song_artist;
      private String song_title;
      private String song_lyric
      private String song_info;
      private String song_mp3_link;
      private String songs_photo_link;
      private String song_date;

      // with getters and setters for all variable

      public int getId() {...}
      public void setId(int id) {...}

      //and other ...

 }
```

now, I want more in 2000 `MySongs` object add to the `List<MySongs>`:

```
 int my_json_data_count = 2000;
 List<MySongs> my_data = new ArrayList();
 for (int i=0; i<my_json_data_count; i++) {
      MySongs mysongs = new MySongs();
      mysongs.setId(...);
      //....
      //...
      my_data.add(mysongs);
 }

 //
 my_data.size(); // 2000
```

Is there a limit to the number of data? (For memory) for 2000 or 3000 or data in arrayList.

Approximately how much of the memory space occupied?

Or at all, the number of data is normal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ArrayList` class is an array based implementation, so, the max number of possible items should coincide with the max number of elements in an array.

In terms of how much memory is occupied, this will depend on the size of your objects stored. You may run out of memory after storing 100 objects, if they are too big, or you may be able to store thousands, if they are small.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know how much memory a given object takes in your heap, you should use [SizeOf](http://sizeof.sourceforge.net/) and call `SizeOf.deepSizeOf` on your object in order to have the deep size of your object.

Please note that the size will depend on the target JVM, indeed the result will change if the target JVM is a `32-bit JVM`, a `64-bit JVM` with `UseCompressedOops` (-XX:+UseCompressedOops) enabled which is the case by default with heaps less than `32 GB` or a `64-bit JVM` with `UseCompressedOops` disabled (-XX:-UseCompressedOops).